# Gnome Ubuntu Hangs and Crashes When Monitor Turned Off

Tags: gnome, crash

I usually just turn off my monitor when I'm going to be gone from the computer for a short period of time. Recently, it's been causing the system to have some major issues. After turning the monitor back on, the system appears to be hanging and is completely unresponsive. Occasionally, it will recover after some time and work normally. Other times, it will remain unresponsive until it reports that the system has encountered and error and cannot recover, forcing me to log out and lose all of my programs. This is very inconvenient. I've investigated the logs, and will attach the parts that seem important (obvs can't attach 100,000 lines of syslog files). They boil down to some Gnome error, supposedly from a plugin, but I haven't installed any myself. The only ones present are Desktop Icons NG, Ubuntu AppIndicators, and Ubuntu Dock.

Some snippets from `/var/log/syslog`: https://pastebin.com/0LGvD2et